# magento use of getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true)

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento and came across this code in a controller

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
```

Although it's name suggest its used to enable adding of js but I have also seen code in design layout xml file without using the above.

Can anyone tell me why we use this.

Answer (score 2):

This adds the configuration for [extJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) parts to the head:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml:16
<?php if($this->getCanLoadExtJs()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = BLANK_IMG;
    Ext.UpdateManager.defaults.loadScripts = false;
    Ext.UpdateManager.defaults.disableCaching = true;
</script>
```

## WE ARE **NOT** TALKING ABOUT EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT.

ExtJS is a library and this method include configuration parameter for this library.

Comment: Hi Fabian, Thank you for your reply. So is this only needed if I am adding external scripts in for the admin ?. Also am I suppose to set this in the controller ?. Thanks

Comment: ext is NOT external, but EXT JS which is a JS library

Comment: Hi Fabian,Thanks again. I get EXT JS is an external js. I have seen code where js is directly included with                                  <reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="jquery">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>                                   ,without using this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true); in the controller. I am just trying to understand when and why we use this. Thanks again

Comment: I edited the post. we are NOT talking about external JS NOT. EXTERNAL. JS. but instead about extJS which is a JS library. IT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH EXTERNAL JS.